# Is it able to crop element in css?

Tags: css, crop

is it able to do something like that?

I was exploring internet and i did not found anything like that, can you please help me with that?

[example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALNNp.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/ Didn't explore the internet much ;p

Comment: literally the first result when searching for css clip image...
https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to physically crop the image? if so, CSS isn't the solution for this.

If you're looking to make it appear as if it's cropped when output to the page then this is possible.

Two methods of doing this are as follows:

**A. Using a Background Image**

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/500/500/animals?t=1519760344548');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

**B. Using an img tag**

HTML

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/500/500/animals?t=1519760344548" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-container{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.img-container img{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

[Here's a fiddle for you.](https://jsfiddle.net/365b31dL/9/)

Comment: Never heard of clip-path, masking, etc?